# Sequelize query include and logic

Tags: sequelize.js

I have three tables: `Article`, `Tag` and `ArticleTag`. An article could have multi tags and a tag could be belongs to multi articles through `ArticleTag`. `Tag` has a `name` property.

I want query all the article which has tags `tag1` and (`tag2` or `tag3`) and (`tag4` or `tag5`).
The following query doesn't work.

```
Article.findAll({
    where: {},
    include: [
        { 
            model: Tag,
            where: {
                [Op.and]: [
                  { name: 'tag1' },
                  { name: { [Op.or]: ['tag2', 'tag3'] } },
                  { name: { [Op.or]: ['tag4', 'tag5'] } },
                ] 
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `having` and `group_by` will get you the expected result ( Please do read comments in below code also ) :

```
Article.findAll({
    where: {},
    include: [
        { 
            model: Tag,
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [ { name: 'tag1' }, { name: 'tag2' }] // change from and to or 
            }
        }
    ]
    group : ['articles.id','tags.id'] , // might need to change table name as per yours
    having : {
        db.sequelize.where(db.sequelize.fn('count', db.sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', db.sequelize.col('articles.id'))),2)                    
    }
});
```

For updated question just change or block within where :

```
[Op.and]: [
    { name: 'tag1' },
    { name: { [Op.or]: ['tag2', 'tag3'] } },
    { name: { [Op.or]: ['tag4', 'tag5'] } },
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it answer my question but don't solve my problem. Maybe I need update my question.

Comment: There is a `having` filter which only accepts data with 2 distinct tags. In the update question, it seems that it is hard to determine this number(2).